# Express change of interests and inclination

Tags: writing

1. > Although I was in the department of A, I became more and more inclined to B. I was looking for more opportunities to study B and
   >   to make up my B's background.

   Which one is better, "I became more and more inclined to B" or "my
   interest became more and more inclined to B".

   If it were you, how would you rewrite the above quote?
2. Suppose C and D are related directions. Neither contains the other
   as a subset. I was doing some things in C, and later I was moving to
   do things in D. Can I say I branch my interest into D?

Thanks!

Comment: Are A and B different fields of study?

Comment: Yes, for example A is biomedical engineering, and B is mathematics. C is computer vision and D is machine learning.

Comment: What about: _I became more interested in B._ As for the second part, I might use, _My interest branched into D_.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would probably write it:

> Although I was in the [biomedical engineering] department, I became more and more inclined **towards** [mathematics]. I was looking for more opportunities to study [mathematics] and to **solidify** my [mathematics] background.

As for 2., I'd say:

> I was studying [computer vision], then I branched into [machine learning].

As far as I know, interests don't branch; people do.